# Give non root user permission to mount NTFS partition

Tags: permissions, mount, gnome, ntfs, nautilus

When an external storage device like a flash drive is plugged in, it gets automatically mounted without any root authentication by nautilus. But why does mounting NTFS partitions within the same internal harddrive require root authentication? How to give a regular user the permission to mount this partition?

Comment: Linux (which distribution)? Unix? Which flavour?

Comment: Sorry. Its my mistake, i didn't mention it. I use Debian Jessie 8.0